# How to Recover Deleted Windows Partition with complete Data?

Tags: 14.04, windows, data-recovery, partitioning

Actual scenario is, while i am installing Ubuntu for the first in my windows machine along with windows OS. accidentally I deleted all other partition and I formatted my entire disk, so i lost my entire data what are all Present on my Disk... i wanna my data back...    is their a solution to recover my Data Back?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully it was only a quick format of your drive (deleting the partition location information). You can use simple utilities like [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to detect the deleted partitions and restore them.

Assuming your disk drive is located at `/dev/sdb`, you can check using `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

Launch `testdisk` and follow the ons screen process to recover your partitions.

Simply: When asked to create logs, select`[No Log`]. Proceed with selecting `[Analyse]` to scan for the deleted partitions. This should detect the drives in your PC where you will be able to select the correct disk and `[Proceed]`. Just select `[Intel]` if you have a MBR disk layout. It will then scan and detect the deleted partitions.
If you are happy with the layout you can then `[Write]` the partition layout to disk. Otherwise you can perform a `[Deeper Search]` to detect partitions that may have been deleted.

This [guide](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-data-recovery.html) here follows the process above with screenshots. Additionally you can burn the [livecd](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd) to a CD or burn the image to a USB stick to get access to the `testdisk` tool.